# KeyReleased equivalence in Android

Tags: java, android, listener

On PC I can add a onKeyListener for a JTextField to listen keyReleased event. On Android I've used addTextChangedListener.

I have two EditText fields in my Android application. Editing one will affect the other. This will cause the program to fail in stack overflow error.

How can I listen for the phone's keyboard instead of changes in the EditText field? I don't want the program to invoke the listener because of the infinite loop caused by the listener.

Comment: And did something stupid and wrote the bounty text wrong...

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to work out which EditText has focus, and ignore events on the other one to avoid infinite looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach a onFocusChangedListener and add the TextChangedListener when a EditText has focus and remove it when it loses focus.
Something like this:

```
 EditText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus){
                        ((EditText) v).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                             //

                        }

                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
                            // 

                        }

                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // affect EditText2

                        }
                    });

                }
                if(!hasFocus){
                    ((EditText) v).removeTextChangedListener();
                }
            }
        });

        }
    });
```

The same for EditText2

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's the right solution, but I cannot see it worth the bounty points, because James.Elsey already posted the solution earlier.

Comment: No problem. The bounty is for a good answer and my answer is just one sentence. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would create one text change listener, something like `SynchronizingWatcher` and attach it to both `EditText`s. Then, when you receive a text change event, before updating other text edits, just unregister old listeners, update text and enable listeners again:

```
class SynchronizingWatcher implements TextWatcher {
  Set<EditText> synchronizedViews = new HashSet<EditText>();

  public void watchView(EditText view) {
    view.addTextChangedListener(this);
    synchronizedViews.add(view);
  }

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    for (EditText editText : synchronizedViews) {
      editText.removeTextChangeListener(this);
      editText.setText(s);  // Of course you can do something more complicated here.
      editText.addTextChangeListener(this);
    }
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // Don't care.
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // Don't care.
  }
}

...
// Somewhere in your activity:
SyncrhonizingWatcher synchronizingWatcher = new SynchronizingWatcher();
synchronizingWatcher.watchView(myEditText1);
synchronizingWatcher.watchView(myEditText1);
```

Another solution: provide your own `KeyListener` that *decorates* existing `KeyListener` (you can get existing key listener with `editText.getKeyListener()` and set your decorator with `editText.setKeyListener()`. Your decorator would also update other edit texts in `onKeyUp()`. But I would try to stay away from messing with that stuff.

Comment: What are you refering to with IdentityHashSet? This? http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/source/browse/trunk/NowPlaying/Android/src/org/metasyntactic/collections/IdentityHashSet.java?spec=svn2310&r=2310

Comment: Sorry, I confused with `IdentityHashMap`. A simple `HashSet<EditText>` should work.

Comment: Well of course, because you're setting something to `height` edit text but not removing text change listener from it, it causes additional ontextchange events.

Comment: But anyway James and Yalla solutions are probably better.