# Attach TextWatcher Class to Multiple EditText without Inifinite Loop

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am trying to calculate the salary the person receives, based on any of the following inputs - hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly. When one of them is entered, the others should be recalculated automatically.

Here's how I proceed:

First, I have 5 `Double` type variables defined at the top of the activity. They are: hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly. Then I have 5 EditText fields, corresponding to these variables. I have attached a custom subclass that implements `TextWatcher` to these 5 EditTexts.

For example:

```
etHourly = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHourly);
etHourly.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etHourly));
```

This custom class has a constructor that accepts and stores the view that was passed to it, since the default methods of the `TextWatcher` class don't provide a way to find out which View invoked the change.

After saving the passed view as a local variable inside the custom subclass I then proceed with the implemented `afterTextChanged` inside this subclass and get the value of the passed EditText and save it as a `Double` to its corresponding defined variable at the top of the activity. (e.g. if the EditText passed is for the Weekly salary, I set the value of this EditText as a double to the `weekly` variable.

Finally, just before the end of the `afterTextChanged` method I call another custom method `Recalculate()`, that has a bunch of `if()`'s to check if hourly, daily, weekly, monthly or yearly is set and if it is, calculate and use `setText()` on the remaining EditText's. The problem is that this `setText()` will invoke the TextWatchers for each of these EditTexts, causing an infinite loop.

How do I overcome this?

Here's some code to have a better understanding of this. Before onCreate:

```
Double hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly = 0.0;
EditText etHourly, etDaily, etWeekly, etMonthly, etYearly;
```

Inside onCreate():

```
etHourly = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHourly);
etDaily = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDaily);
etWeekly = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeekly);
etMonthly = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMonthly);
etYearly = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etYearly);

etHourly.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etHourly));
etDaily.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etDaily));
etWeekly.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etWeekly));
etMonthly.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etMonthly));
etYearly.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(etYearly));
```

The `EditTextWatcher` subclass:

```
private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    EditText v;

    public EditTextWatcher(EditText view) {
        this.v = view;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        Reinit();

        // Only if the currently edited text field contains something
        if (v.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.etHourly:
                hourly = getTvAsDouble(etHourly);
                break;
            case R.id.etDaily:
                daily = getTvAsDouble(etDaily);
                break;
            case R.id.etWeekly:
                weekly = getTvAsDouble(etWeekly);
                break;
            case R.id.etMonthly:
                monthly = getTvAsDouble(etMonthly);
                break;
            case R.id.etYearly:
                yearly = getTvAsDouble(etYearly);
                break;
            default:
            }
        }

        Recalculate();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
    }

}
```

Reinit():

```
hourly = daily = weekly = monthly = yearly = 0.0;
```

Recalculate():

```
if(hourly!=null && hourly>0.0){
      etDaily.setText(String.valueOf(hourly*8));
}
// I will complete the other if's once this works
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyReleased equivalence in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436105/keyreleased-equivalence-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mate !! I too was stuck here .... I was getting the StackOverflowError ...but I was assuming that maybe it is because I have instantiated TextWatcher multiple times ... but you helped me by identifying the problem, which was actually with setText() ,which was calling TextWatcher's methods infinitely .... so here I did it --- as per your code --->

```
if(hourly!=null && hourly>0.0){
 if(etHourly.isFocused())   //this condition helped suppressing infinite loops
  etDaily.setText(String.valueOf(hourly*8));}
```